# Cannot convert 'double' to 'int' C#

Tags: c#, ftp

I have this code =>

```
var timer = new System.Threading.Timer((e) =>
{
    upload();
}, null, 0, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5).TotalMilliseconds);
```

It is supposed to execute this method every 5 minutes, however keeps throwing an
error: Cannot convert 'double' to 'int'. Which is making no sense because I have had other strings in there than "upload()", such as "FTPFileUploader.upload()" and it would work fine. Though I don't want that... Please help... Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

**System.Threading.Timer** Takes an integer, but the following code returns a double

```
TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5).TotalMilliseconds
```

So you need to cast it to an integer:

```
(int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5).TotalMilliseconds
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation on [TimeSpan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx), the constructor requires an int but you are giving it a double instead from the TimeSpan field TotalMilliseconds.

You need to cast your double to an int within the constructor of TimeSpan.

```
(int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5).TotalMilliseconds
```

Answer (score 0):

TotalMilliseconds returns a double, while Milliseconds will return an int as it returns the millisecond portion of the TimeSpan, while TotalMilliseconds returns the total amount represented by the TimeSpan.